# TestLink Report on Execution Type

Tags: test-management, testlink

TestLink has field name - `Execution Type` which could be set for test case. It could be marked as Manual or Automated. I am keen to find a report on this field but did not see any similar report on execution type. There are test case reports for `Failed Test Cases`, `Blocked Test Cases` and `Not run Test Cases` but no test report on execution type. The report on "Execution Type" could give overall picture on how many tests are automated in a plan. (though I know that not many agree with such statistics). 
Is there a way to generate report on `Execution Type` in TestLink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Test Matrix Report.

If this does not have the needed column, register on [TestLink Mantis](http://mantis.testlink.org/login_page.php) and create a feature request (with the maximum level of detail).

Regards

Francisco Mancardi
TestLink Team Leader